# Getting com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host for AWS SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, mssql-jdbc

Kubernets deployment of application on AWS is giving following error while connecting to a SQL Server RDS instance

> org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup Unexpected exception resolving reference
>
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host , port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Tried enabling all the traffic in the security group inbound rule also the ec2 instance VPC and RDS VPC has peer connection link, not sure what is the issue causing this error

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause for this issue, if someone like me stuble upon this question/issue in future then the issue was due to the Route not having the EC2 instance VPC's entries.